# Automatically create file 'requirements.txt'

Tags: python, dependencies, python-import, requirements.txt

Sometimes I download the Python source code from [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) and don't know how to install all the dependencies. If there isn't any *requirements.txt* file I have to create it by hand.

Given the Python source code directory, is it possible to create *requirements.txt* automatically from the import section?

Comment: You can do it by running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` will save all your python libraries with current version into `requirements.txt` file

Comment: @Shaikhul but that doesn't help in the case where you don't have the dependencies installed because you've only just downloaded the package from GitHub...

Comment: Please note: a) `pip freeze` will dump current versions of `all` the installed modules on that system irrespective of there usage in the current project. b) pip will only list modules that have been installed via pip

Comment: If you needed to generate requirements.txt for a lambda layer like I did, you can use `pip freeze` with the `--path` argument as suggested in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210165/pip-freeze-for-packages-installed-with-target

Answer (score 1302, accepted):

Use [Pipenv or other tools](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/#managing-dependencies) is recommended for improving your development flow.

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt  # Python3
pip freeze > requirements.txt  # Python2
```

If you do not use a virtual environment, [pigar](https://github.com/damnever/pigar) will be a good choice for you.

Comment: For anyone erroring, I recommend trying `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` before asking a question.

Comment: I execute `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` and I'm surprised to not find some packages I am actually using such as `argparse` and `configparser`. Is it because they are part of Python core? I believe a better answer is to use `pipreqs` below because it will only list the requirements your project is using.

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland Yes, `argparse` and `configparser` is belong to Python3 standard library, so, what's wrong with `pip3 freeze`? I don't get your point.

Comment: @damnever Ok thank you! `pip3 freeze` gives me the list of all the Python packages installed in my environment whereas `pipreqs` gives me all the ones actually used in my source code which is what I was looking for. Beside that, nothing's wrong with it.

Comment: pipenv has serious issues, see this discussion: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18612590

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes There are some alternatives, such as https://github.com/sdispater/poetry, but I can not recommend them since I use other language more often :-D

Comment: Piping into `requirements.txt` can be [quite a bad idea.](https://medium.com/@tomagee/pip-freeze-requirements-txt-considered-harmful-f0bce66cf895)

Comment: Just created a requirements.txt file with pigars, don't recommend it. Didn't include django-corse-headers dependency which unabled me to even run the application. Good I didn't push it to repo

Answer (score 1464):

You can use the following code to generate a `requirements.txt` file:

```bash
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs /path/to/project
```

The benefits of using `pipreqs` from [its GitHub](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs).

> #### Why not pip freeze?
>
> - `pip freeze` only saves the packages that are installed with `pip install` in your environment.
> - `pip freeze` saves all packages in the environment including those that you don't use in your current project (if you don't have `virtualenv`).
> - and sometimes you just need to create `requirements.txt` for a new project without installing modules.

Comment: thanks. I've got `ubuntu@laptop ~/Desktop/MemNN-hyperopt $ pipreqs ./
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning`  is it ok?

Comment: To be honest I never encountered this before. It does seems caused because your python version can't reliably be used for SSL connections. There are some workarounds enlisted at  https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2681, I also read that upgrading your python version might help. Perhaps some expert on this matter can give better advice?

Comment: @IgorBarinov thats a Warning and won't create a problem to run `pipreqs`, I installed it on python 2.6 and got same warning but it does create a `requirements.txt` file, thanks @DJanssens

Comment: @Shaikhul if you got these warnings you will not have a full file, you will just get a part of requirements. You can check it on https://github.com/npow/MemNN/tree/hyperopt repo. I have only 'hyperopt == 0.0.2
numpy == 1.9.2
scikit_learn == 0.16.1
theano == 0.7.0'

Comment: And I use standard Python 2.7.6 on a fresh MacOS X Yosemite

Comment: [that said](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning) `it is strongly recommended to upgrade to a newer Python version`

Comment: @IgorBarinov what requreiments were you expecting to get on the project github.com/npow/MemNN/tree/hyperopt ? I see only numpy, scikit, theano as external packages that were installed using pip, other ones are native

Comment: This doesn't work for Python 3.6, if the new print statement output formatting is uesd.

Comment: @AnandCU what happens ? I see in the project it does reference py3.6 https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=python3+&type=

Comment: @AnandCU update; It looks like it is fixed now, but in the code, not yet a release; see this PR https://github.com/damnever/pigar/pull/40

Comment: I used pipreqs and needed to specify the used charset in my scanned projectfolder - otherwise I received an error generated by pipreqs: `pipreqs --encoding utf-8`

Comment: Note: This will not include installed apps in your settings that are not explicitly imported in your views but nonetheless being used in the background.

Comment: @chaudim Including, for example, the python module for your database driver.

Comment: I have got the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1359: character maps to <undefined>`. Solution `pipreqs --encoding=utf8 path_to`, more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511050/9913319

Comment: These project seems good, but must be checked because in some cases give the wrong version of the used modules. It seems as if it checks the names of the required  modules in files but shows the most current version available for install no the current used version that is really installed at the environment.

Comment: Important notice: this variant can be bad. Use virtualenv and pip3 freeze > requirements.txt. Let me explain: pipreqs only saves packages which are imported in project, not their dependencies. Sometimes package maintainer write requirement rule like this: "Jinja2>=2.10" (this is from `setup.py` of Flask 1.02 package). So the incompatible major version can be installed (in my example i got Jinja 3.1.0) and breaks everything.

Comment: this doesn't get all my requirements

Comment: Be aware that there is a bug in `pipreqs` that generates the wrong package version under certain circumstances. See [bug ticket on github](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/265).

Comment: If you get `ConnectionError` try using `python3 -m pipreqs.pipreqs --use-local .` instead

Comment: does not work: I type "pipreqs --ecnoding utf-8 /path/to/my_project", and receive: "Usage:
    pipreqs [options] [<path>]"

Comment: I just tried it (caveat: my pip3 is outdated) and the resulting requirements.txt file had multiple versions of a few packages listed in it.  I had to edit it by hand to remove all but the most recent ones before I could successfully feed it to `pip3 install -r`

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 140):

For python3: (I have both python 2 and 3 on my machine, where python2 is the default)

```
# install
pip3 install pipreqs

# Run in current directory
python3 -m  pipreqs.pipreqs .
```

python2:

```
pip install pipreqs
python -m  pipreqs.pipreqs .
```

To check your python version:

```
python --version
```

Comment: Worked for me with a slight modifcation: `pip install pipreqs` and then `python -m  pipreqs.pipreqs .`

Comment: I needed `python -m pipreqs.pipreqs --encoding=utf8 --force` because of some UTF8 characters (in my code, I guess?), [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511050/1175496)

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 63):

Kinda mind-blowing how this simple task is so complicated in Python. Here is what I think is the best way to do it automatically.

You need two tools:

1.[pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

`pip3 install pipreqs`

pipreqs will go through your project and only install the packages that your project use. Instead of all the packages in your python environment as `pip freeze` would do.

But there's a problem with this approach. It does not install the sub-packages.

For example, your project uses `pandas==1.3.2`. `pandas` itself uses `numpy==1.21.2` among other packages. But `pipreqs` itself does not write the sub-packages (i.e. numpy) in `requirments.txt`

This is where you need to combine `pipreqs` with the second tool.

2. [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)

`pip3 install pip-tools`

`pip-tools` will take the packages in `requirements.in` and generate the `requirements.txt` with all the sub-packages. For example, if you have
`pandas==1.3.2` in `requirements.in`, `pip-tools` would generate

`numpy==1.21.2 # via pandas` in `requirements.txt`.

But you need to manually add the package in `requirements.in`. Which is prone to mistake and you might forget to do this once in a while.

This is where you can use the first tool.

But both the tools write to `requirements.txt`. So how do you fix it?

Use the  `--savepath` for `pipreqs` to write in `requirements.in` instead of the default `requirements.txt`.

To do it in one command; just do

`pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in && pip-compile`

There you go. Now you don't need to worry about manually maintaining the packages and you're `requirements.txt` will have all the sub-packages so that your build is deterministic.

**TL;DR**

1. `pip3 install pipreqs`
2. `pip3 install pip-tools`

Use the following to build a deterministic `requirements.txt`

`pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in && pip-compile`

Comment: It should be `pip install pip-tools` instead of `pip install pip-tool`

Comment: When I ran  `pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in && pip-compile`, `pipreqs` created a `requirements.in` file in addition to `requirements.txt`. Can you elaborate in your post or a comment why `requirements.in` is generated?

Comment: @SergeiWallace i don't know if this is still useful to you, but it created requriements.in because `pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in && pip-compile` has `--savepath=requirements.in` with a `in` extension not txt

Comment: @SergeiWallace The `requirements.in` file is only used as an intermediate file which `pip-compile`  then uses to generate the final `requirements.txt`.

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 55):

In my case, I use [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), so running the following command from a [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) terminal inside my environment solved it, and created this *requirements.txt* file for me automatically:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

This was taken from this Github link [pratos/condaenv.txt](https://gist.github.com/pratos/e167d4b002f5d888d0726a5b5ddcca57).

If an error have been seen, and you are using Anaconda, try to use the `.yml` option:

```
conda env export > <environment-name>.yml
```

For another person to use the environment or if you are creating a new environment on another machine:

```
conda env create -f <environment-name>.yml
```

[.yml option been found here](https://gist.github.com/pratos/e167d4b002f5d888d0726a5b5ddcca57)

Comment: if you're not using a virtual environment, this will create an overly long requirements.txt file

Comment: Does this actually work? Whenever I have tried this there are dependencies and syntax particulars that `pip install requirements.txt` rejects.

Comment: I found some errors using the .txt, so just added the other option that worked with me too..."Using the .yml" mentioned above.

Answer (score 43):

I blindly followed the accepted answer of using
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt

It generated a huge file that listed all the dependencies of the entire solution, which is not what I wanted.

So you need to figure out what sort of requirements.txt you are trying to generate.

If you **need a requirements.txt file that has ALL the dependencies**, then use the pip3

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

However, if you want to **generate a minimal requirements.txt that only lists the dependencies you need**, then **use the pipreqs package**. Especially *helpful if you have numerous requirements.txt files in per component level in the project* and not a single file on the solution wide level.

```
pip install pipreqs
pipreqs [path to folder]
e.g. pipreqs .
     pipreqs . --force --ignore=tests (Overwrites exisiting requirements.txt, ignores the tests directory)
```

Comment: If you don't to include subdirectories, you can add the --ignore <dirs> flag to your command

Comment: If you require Juptyer notebook support, you can see jltz2's answer below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68544207/1622880

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 29):

As most of the answers using `pipreqs` didn't work for me. Here, is my answer.

To generate the requirements.txt file:

```
pip install pipreqs

python -m  pipreqs.pipreqs --encoding utf-8  /path/to/project
```

I prefer using `pipreqs` more than `pip freeze`, as `pip freeze` saves all packages in the environment including those that you don't use in your current project. However, `pipreqs` only save the ones you are using in your project.

To install the requirements use:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried this but it missed some packages. I think this only grabs from the import statements, so it can miss some things you need, and will cause errors on deployment.

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned, use it if you only want those packages, not all the packages in the environment.

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 20):

Firstly, your project file must be a py file which is direct python file. If your file is in ipynb format, you can convert it to py type by using the line of code below:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to=python
```

Then, you need to install pipreqs library from cmd (terminal for mac).

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Now we can create txt file by using the code below. If you are in the same path with your file, you can just write ./ . Otherwise you need to give path of your file.

```
pipreqs ./
```

or

```
pipreqs /home/project/location
```

That will create a requirements.txt file for your project.

Comment: I get `No template sub-directory with name 'python' found in the following paths`

Comment: You can try uninstalling and installing nbconvert using:


pip uninstall nbconvert
pip install nbconvert

@koppor

Answer (score 17):

You can just do it with the following commands. It will create file *requirement.txt* and add relevant modules automatically.

For Unix:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

For Windows:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I think the difference between using `pip3` and `pip` is coming from the Python Version difference.
Not necessarily from the operating system that is used, CMIIW.


`For Python3 : pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`
`For Python2: pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 15):

#### Create file *requirement.txt*

For the Python 3 version, the command is:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

For the Python 2 version, the command is:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

#### Install *requirements.txt*

For the Python 3 version, the command is:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

For the Python 2 version, the command is:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Automatic requirements.txt updating approach

While developing a Python application with **requirements.txt** we have several choices:

1. Generate *requirements.txt* after development, when we want to deploy it. It is performed by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or `pipreqs` for less messy result.
2. Add every module to file *requirements.txt* manually after each install.
3. Install manager that will handle *requirements.txt* updates for us.

There are many answers for the first option, the second option is self-explanatory, so I would like to describe the third approach. There is a library called **to-requirements.txt**. To install it, type this:

```
pip install to-requirements.txt  # Pip install to requirements.txt
```

If you read the whole command at once, you would see what it does. After installing you should set it up. Run:

```
requirements-txt init
```

It overrides the pip scripts so that each `pip install` or `pip uninstall` updates the *requirements.txt* file of your project automatically with required versions of packages. The overriding is made safely, so that after uninstalling this package the pip will behave ordinary.

And you could **customize** the way it works. For example, disable it globally and activate it only for the required directories, activate it only for git repositories, or allow / disallow to create requirements.txt file if it does not exist.

**References:**

1. [Documentation](https://requirements-txt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. [GitHub](https://github.com/VoIlAlex/requirements-txt)
3. [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/to-requirements.txt/)

Answer (score 11):

**Make sure to run pip3 for python3.7.**

```
pip3 freeze >> yourfile.txt
```

Before executing the above command make sure you have created a virtual environment.

**python3:**

```
pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m venv <myenvname>
```

**python2**:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <myenvname>
```

After that put your source code in the directory. If you run the python file now, probably it won't launch if you are using non-native modules. You can install those modules by running `pip3 install <module>` or `pip install <module>`.

This will not affect you entire module list except the environment you are in.

Now you can execute the command at the top and now you have a requirements file which contains only the modules you installed in the virtual environment. Now you can run the command at the top.

I advise everyone to use environments as it makes things easier when it comes to stuff like this.

Answer (score 9):

## Simple Pythonic Way

To get a list of all the *REQUIREMENTS* in a standard `requirements.txt` file, you can use the following command.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Now, this should automatically create a **standard requirements file** with all of the packages installed alongside their corresponding versions.

### Pretty Print on Terminal

If you just want to get a pretty print on the terminal you can use the following approach.

```
pip list
```

This lists all of the installed packages, in a pretty print format.

## Custom Dependency

If you have a project folder like say, a Github Repo, and you want to get a **custom requirements.txt for project** You can use the following Package.
**https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/** `pipreqs`

### Usage

```
$ pipreqs /home/project/location
Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
```

Contents of requirements.txt

```
wheel==0.23.0
Yarg==0.1.9
docopt==0.6.2
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed many dependencies in your system and you need requirements.txt for a specific project, you can install first pipreqs:

```
$ pip install pipreqs
```

and execute the below command under the project folder.

```
$ pipreqs
```

This command will generate requirements.txt file for the particular project.

Comment: https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs appears to be dead: "build no longer available" badge, "Looking for maintainers to move this project forward." Version installed from `pip` crashed on a small toy project.

Answer (score 7):

If Facing the same issue as mine i.e. **not on the virtual environment** and wants requirements.txt **for a specific project** or from the **selected folder(includes children)** and pipreqs is not supporting.

**You can use :**

```
import os
import sys
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import subprocess

path = "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/DjangoProjects/restAPItest"


files = os.listdir(path)
pyfiles = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
      for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.py'):
              pyfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))

stopWords = ['from', 'import',',','.']

importables = []

for file in pyfiles:
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.readlines()

        for line in content:
            if "import" in line:
                for sw in stopWords:
                    line = ' '.join(line.split(sw))

                importables.append(line.strip().split(' ')[0])

importables = set(importables)

subprocess.call(f"pip freeze > {path}/requirements.txt", shell=True)

with open(path+'/requirements.txt') as req:
    modules = req.readlines()
    modules = {m.split('=')[0].lower() : m for m in modules}


notList = [''.join(i.split('_')) for i in sys.builtin_module_names]+['os']

new_requirements = []
for req_module in importables:
    try :
        new_requirements.append(modules[req_module])

    except KeyError:
        for k,v in modules.items():
            if len(req_module)>1 and req_module not in notList:
                if fuzz.partial_ratio(req_module,k) > 90:
                    new_requirements.append(modules[k])

new_requirements = [i for i in set(new_requirements)]

new_requirements

with open(path+'/requirements.txt','w') as req:
    req.write(''.join(new_requirements))
```

P.S: It may have a few additional libraries as it checks on fuzzylogic.

Answer (score 6):

@Francis has it right - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65728461/1021819

But just to add:

With additional support for Jupyter notebooks - i.e. `.ipynb` files - you can now use https://pypi.org/project/pipreqsnb (same syntax as pipreqs):

```bash
pip install pipreqsnb
pipreqsnb .
```

[I am not an author]

Comment: This works great, but you need to use the command as `pipreqsnb .`, not `pipreqs .`

Answer (score 5):

best way for Python 3 is:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

it worked for me...

Comment: Excuse me but how is your answer different to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33468993/5791355?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to list only packages used inside a virtualenv use:

```
pip freeze -l > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete solution, but may help to compile a shortlist on Linux.

```
grep --include='*.py' -rhPo '^\s*(from|import)\s+\w+' . | sed -r 's/\s*(import|from)\s+//' | sort -u > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you are using something like [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), you can just run this command to generate a *requirements.txt* file:

```
./.venv/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this bash command.

```
for l in $(pip freeze); do p=$(echo "$l" | cut -d'=' -f1); f=$(find . -type f -exec grep "$p" {} \; | grep 'import'); [[ ! -z "$f" ]] && echo "$l" ; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is a bad way to create the requirements file! It can serve as a temporary solution for your problem, but when managing requirements for a Python project it is best to do it manually.

A simple search for "import" or "from x import" will give you the list of all dependencies that need to be installed (nothing extra).

**The problem with `pip freeze`** it that it simply dumps all installed packages with strict versions, every dependency has its own dependencies and they are included in the dump.
For example, you have lib==1.0 installed, that needs sub-lib==0.5, if you use `pip freeze` you'll get both, but later when you wish to update the version of lib to 2.0, most likely you'll get conflicts since lib v2.0 now uses sub-lib v1.0, not the v0.5 that you require... This [gets complex fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444289/from-virtualenv-pip-freeze-requirements-txt-give-tones-of-garbage-how-to-tri) for multiple dependencies.

We got into those problems in a couple of projects, and since then I created [an automated script](https://github.com/eyalyoli/python-dev-tools) to clean `pip freeze`'s dumps. It is safe (comments unneeded dependencies) and works great.

Answer (score 0):

To help solve this problem, always run requirements.txt on only local packages. By local packages I mean packages that are only in your project folder. To do this do:
Pip freeze —local > requirements.txt

Not pip freeze > requirements.txt.
Note that it’s double underscore before local.

However installing pipreqs helps too.
Pip install pipreqs.

The perfect solution though is to have a pipfile. The pipfile updates on its own whenever you install a new local package. It also has a pipfile.lock similar to package.json in JavaScript.
To do this always install your packages with pipenv not pip.
So we do pipenv

Comment: I have a project which only needs robotframework and rpaframework.

I have tried both `pipreqs` -> it gives me just robotframework
then `pip freeze > requirements.txt` gives many libraries which not in used in the project.

how do I use these tool/command to output the requiremnt correctly?

it will helps in setting up the new environment.

Comment: What do you mean by *"run requirements.txt"*? Create? Use? Change? Something else? Overwrite? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72116250/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Pipenv users can generate the `requirement.txt` file from the project's Pipfile with:

```
pipenv lock --requirements
```

Comment: Error: No such option: --requirements Did you mean --quiet?

Answer (score 0):

For a different use case from the original question, where you do have the environment but have not pinned your dependencies, I found `pipreqs` to be inconsistent as it would sometimes duplicate dependencies with different versions like two entries of pillow with version `9.0.0` and `9.5.0` as well as fail to catch some needed dependencies.

I realized `pipreqs` is overkill for me personally.
I saw several people mention that `pip freeze` comes with caveat of storing ALL of your environments packages.
However, there is a simple solution that works well for me:

Sort out unpinned top level requirements into dev and core files like so:

```bash
requirements
├── core.txt
└── dev.txt
```

Since you probably only want your core requirements for production,

```bash
pip freeze | grep -F -f requirements/core.txt > requirements.txt
```

And let's say you wanted to omit extra like trailing `+cpu` at the end of the requirement names (which I needed to do for a Hugging Face deployment), you could chain a piped filter beforehand.

`pip freeze | grep -F -f requirements/core.txt | sed 's/+cpu//g' > requirements.txt`

I find this much simpler to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

`pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in && pip-compile`

It won't be working if you are on Windows [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell).

Try this;

`( pipreqs --savepath=requirements.in ) -and (pip-compile)`