# execute hello world with flask "ImportError: No module named flask"

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use flask and python. I did a simple file named `hello.py`. tHis file contains this code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is a simple hello world with flask. I want to execute it but actually, I have a problem. In the terminal, I typed `python hello.py` 
and I get this error:

```
File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Even that I installed flask globally.
I understand that this is a basic question, but I'm stuck?

Comment: Just run `apt-get install python-flask`

Comment: If you are on windows : py -2 -m pip install flask (for python3 use -3)

Comment: Had this before, have you got more than one instance of python running? Sometimes Flask installs in 3 for example but the terminal/command line is in 2 etc

Comment: Please run `python -m pip list`? Is Flask listed? If not, run `python -m pip install flask`.

Answer (score 23):

You don't have installed `flask`

### Linux:

Install `flask` as global package:

```
sudo pip install flask
```

Install in virtualenv

```
virtualenv venv
source venv
pip install flask
```

Install system package

- debian, ubuntu

  ```
  apt-get install python-flask
  ```
- arch

  ```
  pacman -S python-flask
  ```
- fedora

  ```
  yum install python-flask
  ```

Install via [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)

```
conda install flask
```

### Windows:

```
python -m pip install flask
```

Comment: I'm not sure since OP said: *Even that I installed flask globally. I understand that this is a basic question, but I'm stuck?*

Comment: By the way, there's also some Red Hat, Fedora Linux.

Comment: @KevinGuan Run console / terminal and type: `python -V` and next type `pip list`

Answer (score 1):

You've installed flask for python2 you need to use sudo pip3 install ... to get it for python3. I had spent a day when I got that I was using pip for python 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install flask with
pip install flask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you entered the correct entry into the requirements.txt file. It should not be blank.

enter Flask==2.0.0 into the requirements.txt file.

Comment: Rather than editing the requirements.txt file manually, it should be auto-generated it so that you are sure it matches your current environment. See [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)

Comment: It was nice to know that it could be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install flask package globally using the following command,

```
pip install flask
```

Still you are having the same error then you have more than one version of python installed in your machine. So better to create a virtual environment for your app and install all package in it. For that install virtual environment.

```
py -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

Activate your `venv` by

```
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Now try to install flask in the `venv`

```
python -m virtualenv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

if you install the flask and still get the error. Then, You should activate the source by following:

source env/bin/activate

Comment: This solution is already provided in another answer. If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.