# How to use python venv with both site packages and pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

When I run python venv:

```
python -m venv test-env
. test-env/bin/activate
```

I have virtual environment with `pip` avaliable (although it's not avaliable for my outside the  venv. However, in this environment all packages need to be installed, which are already avaliable globally. I learned I have to set `venv` with `--system-site-packages` flag. But when I do this:

```
python -m venv --system-site-packages test-env
. test-env/bin/activate
```

I can't use `pip` inside the virtual environment, so it's pointless, because I can't install any additional packages.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use a requirements file to install packages in your venv.

Comment: Where is this file? Should I use the `--system-site-packages` flag in this case?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files

Answer (score 0):

> I can't use pip inside the virtual environment, so it's pointless, because I
>    can't install any additional packages. How to solve this problem?

A bit to early to give up on `pip`! You can add any package you want in the new environment, eg:

```
pip install pandas
```

Looks like you are unsure about a list of your dependencies. They are normally stored in a file called `requirements.txt`, which is specific to a project. For example, a github repository ususally has `requirements.txt` - so that users can replicate the dependcies.

You can create `requirements.txt` manually, or use `pip freeze` after you have installed the packages you want one by one. A bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt).

Also recommended to look at [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/), which combines `virtualenv` and `pip` functionality under one roof.