# Pipreqs: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1206: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, character-encoding, anaconda, python-unicode

When I use `pipreqs`, I have this problem. I use anaconda and Russian Windows.

```
root@DESKTOP-ETLLRI1 C:\Users\root\Desktop\resumes
$ pipreqs C:\Users\root\Desktop\resumes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\Scripts\pipreqs-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 396, in main
    init(args)
  File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 341, in init
    extra_ignore_dirs=extra_ignore_dirs)
  File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py", line 75, in get_all_imports
    contents = f.read()
  File "C:\Users\root\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1206: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can pass an encoding argument to `pipreqs` to set the encoding to use to open files.

Python3 files are [usually encoded as utf-8](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=source%20file%20encoding#lexical-analysis), so execute

`pipreqs --encoding=utf8 C:\Users\root\Desktop\resumes`

Comment: I had to set a parameter to ignore my env as well as the parameter to specify utf8. https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues/214