# Dependencies auto discovery for Python setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

In packaging a Python application using `setuptools`, I am populating the `install_requires` list with all the PyPI dependencies of my application. I find myself manually combing through all my sources to find these. Is this the right way to do it? Or can this list be auto-populated somehow?

Comment: You should only list the direct dependencies in `install_requires` (not the indirect ones, the dependencies of your dependencies), so this should be a relatively short list and you probably should curate this list by hand. There are probably ways to automate this of course, I think I have seen such tools before, but I don't see the point really, so I haven't used them and can't recall their names.

Comment: Hi Sinoroc, good to know I'm doing it right, but - curious - why should this list be curated by hand instead of automated? I found myself missing direct dependencies initially because I missed looking at a source file.

Comment: Thinking about it again, it would be nice to have a tool that could analyze the code of the current project and tell you which of the libraries installed in the environment are direct dependencies of the current project. It could be helpful indeed. So far I have always done it by hand, I use [_tox_](https://pypi.org/project/tox/), which would probably tell me if I missed one direct dependency, but wouldn't say anything if have one unnecessary library in `install_requires`.

Comment: Missing in my previous comment: I combine _tox_ with a _linting_ tool such as [_pylint_](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) to get notified if some _imports_ can't be resolved, which means that some library is missing in `install_requires`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/), seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/11138259

Comment: @sinoroc Looks useful! It has the added benefit of specifying the versions being used as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view `install_requires` should only list the **direct** dependencies of your project (not the indirect ones, the dependencies of your dependencies). So it often is a relatively short list, that can probably should be curated by hand, the same way you carefully hand-picked your libraries to begin with.

In common scenarios, using [*tox*](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) in combination with a *linting* tool such as [*pylint*](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/) would let you know if some *imports* can't be resolved, which most likely means that libraries are missing from `install_requires`.

In the case you already have lots of dependencies but lost track of which ones and didn't keep `install_requires` up to date, then I believe a tool such as [*pipreqs*](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/) or [*pigar*](https://pypi.org/project/pigar/) can help (there are probably other similar tools, but that's the ones I stumbled upon while browsing the following similar questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61143402/11138259), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/11138259)).