# How do I make a requirement.txt for a .py file? Not all modules installed via pip, but ones concerning some specific .py file only

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I want to make requirement.txt file which contains modules required to run that file only. 
I don't want to use : pip freeze > requirements.txt as it takes all the installed modules, even ones not required to run that file.

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependencies auto discovery for Python setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130177/dependencies-auto-discovery-for-python-setuptools)