# Get and install requirements.txt for python file into virtualenv

Tags: pip, python-import, python-packaging, requirements.txt

I have the following packages I need to install into my virtual environment for an app deployment. This is how they read at the top of my app's file:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from scipy import stats
from sklearn import metrics
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

I'm not sure how to install the ones that say "from x import y, z". I'd also much prefer to do something more global(?) than install each thing one by one into the virtualenv.

As I understand it, the pip freeze > requirements.txt command only generates a requirements file based on what's manually been installed into the virtualenv. I'd rather get something together that looks at my app file and generates a requirements.txt based on that, and then install the contents of the requirements.txt into the virtualenv directly, as opposed to installing each package one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependencies auto discovery for Python setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130177/dependencies-auto-discovery-for-python-setuptools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from foo import bar` is essentially equivalent to:

```py
import foo
bar = foo.bar
```

It just imports the module then loads some of its variables into scope. So, `from scipy import stats` would be in the `scipy` module. As for automatically generating a `requirements.txt`, this is what [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) is made for.

Answer (score 0):

I installed pipreqs and then used

```
pipreqs .
```

from command line while in the directory of the folder with the app in it. This generated a requirements.txt with all the proper packages. Still working on installing the requirements.txt into the virtualenv, but thats been answered many times elsewhere.

EDIT: install requirements.txt into virtualenv using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```