# How to check requirements and generate a requirements.txt file

Tags: python

I have a simple code that runs on a VPS and I want to know how I can check if the required modules are installed when my script is run. I also need to find a way to generate a list of modules the script uses when run on my local machine in-order to use it in the VPS. I've read many questions and answers but they all are linked to many complex methods that I can't understand at all.

Comment: Does this answer your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt

Comment: Refer this link I believe this will be easy to understand as well http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-find-out-what-modules-a-python-script-requires/

Comment: @Mark Meyer is there a way to get the modules that are only used by the script? `pip > freeze` created a list of all my modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Method 1:

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt) will explain how you can export a list of packages - regardless of whether they are used in your project or not. You could then manually filter through and remove the redundant ones yourself.

## Method 2:

You can use the [pip-check-reqs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-check-reqs/) package to *check* for missing dependencies not currently in your `requirements.txt` file -- which you can then add to it manually. Unfortunately, it currently doesn't output version information.

## Method 3:

Combine the above two methods together. Write a script that will use the requirements list generated from the first method, and filter it according to those generated using the second method.

## Method 4 (Legacy):

There used to be a great little package called [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/). It would generate a suitable `requirements.txt` file for you automatically. Unfortunately, it broke sometime around or after Python 3.6. I'm currently not aware of any alternative package.

Comment: pipreqs works for me in python 3.11. I guess it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One simple method to generate a requirements.txt file is to pipe them,

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Make sure you are in the directory where you need to create the requirements.txt file and use the above-mentioned command in the terminal and it will do the rest for you.