# How do I install a dependency on a python pip project that doesn't provide requirements.txt?

Tags: python, git, npm, pip, dependencies

I am trying to contribute to python's `pip` module.

However, some pip modules do not include `requirements.txt` in their source code repository.

In this situation, when i clone the project and run the test code, the following error occurs.

```sh
$ python test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'
```

Of course, if i install it with `pip install mock`, i can prevent an error that occurs because the mock module does not exist, but there is a high possibility that an error may occur due to other modules as follows.

```sh
$ pip install mock
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ python test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nose'
```

---

**How can I install all the dependencies of a cloned project at once?**

The project I want to contribute is [python-ipmi](https://github.com/kontron/python-ipmi).

---

For example, the modules of `node.js` include package.json in the source code repository.

For this reason, if i clone the project and `npm install`, i can download all of the module's dependent modules.

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js

$ npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to generate a requirements.txt file:

```
pip install pipreqs

pipreqs /path/to/project
```

for more info, check out [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt)