# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json==1.0.0

Tags: python, json, requirements.txt

I am trying to host my discord bot (coded in Python) on Heroku, but I am facing this error. How do I correctly include the json package in requirements.txt?

**bot.py file**

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json


def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open("prefixes.json", "r") as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
```

**requirements.txt file**

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
dnspython==1.16.0
PyNaCl==1.3.0
async-timeout==3.0.1
json==1.0.0
```

Comment: Could you show us what code you have written?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is a built-in Python module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to install the json module, because it is a [built-in module with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Just `import json` and it should just work out-of-the-box. If you are using some *other* JSON library, then it's probably not named as `json` because Python already has that. You will have to search PyPi for the correct name of the package: https://pypi.org/search/?q=json.

Also, it seems you are *manually* creating your requirements.txt. It's better that you don't do that because you might miss packages or write incorrect ones (like this json module). You can use [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/):

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
aiohttp==3.7.3
appnope==0.1.2
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==20.3.0
backcall==0.2.0
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
datasize==1.0.0
decorator==4.4.2
elasticsearch==7.10.1
elasticsearch-dsl==7.3.0
Flask==1.1.2
...
```

See related post: [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684375/2745495).