# How to export virtual environment on a remote server?

Tags: python, virtualenv, remote-server, modulenotfounderror

I want to run python scripts on a remote server. I put my code under a directory using FileZilla, and I connect to the server using PuTTY. When I run my scripts, I have a `ModuleNotFound` error because I didn't install packages on the remote server. However, I'm not allowed to do a `pip install` on the server.

So I thought about using a virtual environment to manage it. But how can I export the virtual environment on the remote server?

Or is there a better way to manage it?

Thank you

Comment: Depending on the type of the modules you might not be able to just copy the environment. The best way is to recreate it from `requirements.txt`. If you don't have proper shell access, the server might not be suitable for a Python deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this command on cmd of you computer

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

then copy the file the virtual remote directory
the open cmd  in virtual remote

```
cd C://< where you copied the file>
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or you can use this suggestion
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/16270009

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowing to use the `pip install` command on the remote server

Comment: Just create a virtual environment on the remote server, activate it, and proceed as described above.