# How to add 'matplotlib' to readthedocs.yaml or requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

The scene:

- wrote my own python package
- used sphinx to create documentation for said package
- I'm now trying to upload said documentation to readthedocs

The problem:

When I try to build the documentation, I end up with an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`. I spent about two hours trying to figure out how to fix this, and I've added my `.readthedocs.yaml` and `requirements.txt` files, but I just copied what was on the readthedocs website, I can't find anything about how to add additional Python packages to these files (specifically what text I use to do so). I mean, everything says you *can*, and that you can add via the config or the yaml or through conda, but no example text. I really just need a simple example: "to add matplotlib module, add **foo text** to requirements.txt" or something like it

I'm sure it's a really simple obvious answer to people who work with this all the time, but this is my first time trying to publish documentation. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand - you can open `requirements.txt` in any text editor and add text manually. And `.readthedocs.yaml` is also normal text file so you can open it in any text editor.

Comment: @furas Yes, I understand that part. What I'm saying is I don't know what text to add.

Comment: did you open `requirements.txt` in text editor? It should explain everything. You need new line with at least text `matplotlib` - and it will install the newest version. If you need some special version then you need `matplotlib==version` or `matplotlib>=version` if you need `version` or newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version of `matplotlib` that your package depends on like so:

```py
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.3.4'
```

The format for `requirements.txt` is like `packagename==version`, so you should add the following line:

```
matplotlib==3.3.4
```

If using a Linux command-line, you can also do it this way:

```
$ pip freeze | grep matplotlib
matplotlib==3.3.4
```

If working in a virtual environment where only the required packages are installed, you don't even need to do this by hand for each package; since `pip freeze` generates output in the correct format, you can just save the output of `pip freeze` to generate your whole `requirements.txt` file (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684375/automatically-create-requirements-txt) for more details):

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```