# How to check if all packages listed in requirements.txt file are used in Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, requirements.txt

I have a requirements file which contains all installed packages. After big refactoring process of the project some of the listed packages are not needed anymore. The problem is I'm not sure which.
Is there a way to determine which packages listed in the requirements.txt file are actually used in the code?

Comment: Do you have automated tests that you can run, ideally with high coverage? The brute force approach is to start with an empty venv, run your tests, and install the packages for each modulenotfounderror,.. until all the tests pass.

Comment: `$ cat **/*.py | grep import` could be a starting point?

Comment: @GinoMempin actually my project is a big cutsom build test automation framework for some product, and it does not have any additional tests.

Comment: @aviya.developer so you;re suggestion is the to write additional script that will grep all of the imported packages? I will probably use this as a last resort. For now I'm thinking of more elegant solution.

Comment: `python -v …` Take notes, be fast! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer that uses a Python library: `pipreqs`. See [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/5763413).

Running pipreqs with the default arguments will generate a `requirements.txt` for you.

```sh
$ pipreqs /home/project/location
Successfully saved requirements file in /home/project/location/requirements.txt
```

However, it looks like you're trying to clean up an old `requirements.txt` file. In this case, `pipreqs` also comes with a `--diff` flag, and a `--clean` flag. From the docs:

```sh
--diff <file>         Compare modules in requirements.txt to project imports.
--clean <file>        Clean up requirements.txt by removing modules that are not imported in project.
```

You can use `--diff` to determine which libraries need to be removed, and `--clean` to do it automagically.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a virtual environment and have a *decent enough* test suite that you can repeatedly and automatically run (it's best if you can run it on your local workspace via a script or a simple command), then the *brute-force* type of approach is to:

1. Setup a fresh copy of your project (ex. `git clone` onto a separate folder)
2. Setup an empty/blank virtual environment
3. Run your tests
4. Install missing packages every time you encounter a "ModuleNotFoundError" type of error
5. Repeat until all tests passes
6. Export the packages you now have to a separate **requirements.txt** file (`pip freeze > requirements.new.txt` or any of the other ways from  [Automatically create requirements.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684375/2745495))

For example, we have this (very) minimal example code:

```
# --- APP CODE

from numpy import array
from openpyxl import Workbook
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    x: int

# --- TEST CODE

import pytest

def test_my_model():
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        MyModel(x="not an int")
```

After cloning this and setting up a brand new fresh virtual environment (but without yet installing any of the packages), the 1st attempt to run the tests yields:

```
(my_venv) $ pytest --maxfail=1 main.py
bash: /Users/me/.venvs/my-proj-7_w3b8eb/bin/pytest: No such file or directory
```

So then, you install **pytest**.

Then, you get:

```
(my_venv) $ pytest --maxfail=1 main.py
...
main.py:1: in <module>
    from numpy import array
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

So then you install **numpy**.

Then, you get:

```
(my_venv) $ pytest --maxfail=1 main.py
...
main.py:2: in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

So then you install **openpyxl**.

...and so on. *Until all the tests passes.* Of course, even when your automated tests pass, it's good to *also* do some manual basic tests to make sure everything is *indeed* working as before. Finally, generate a new copy of your requirements.txt file, and compare that with the old one, to check for any differences.

Of course, as I mentioned at the start, this assumes you have a *decent enough* test suite that tests a large % of your code and use cases. (It's also one of the good reasons why you should be writing tests in the first place.).