# fail to install requirements using "pip install -r requirements.txt"

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install packages using "pip install -r requirements.txt" command on bash in Window.
Below shows the requirements.txt

```
Package Version
- - - -  - - - - 
absl-py                      1.0.0
appdirs                      1.4.4
astroid                      2.11.2
astunparse                   1.6.3
audioread                    2.1.9
black                        22.3.0
cachetools                   5.0.0
certifi                      2021.10.8
~~~~                         ~~~~~
```

However, I got a Error like:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'Package Version' (from line 1 of requirements.txt)

And then, I tried without first line in requirements.txt, but I got the same error message.
How can I handle this problem?

Comment: That isn't a valid requirements.txt file, you should recreate it with `pip freeze` if you can

Comment: this requirement.txt is generated form anaconda? or you just copy the package details from command there and paste it

Comment: I'm curious as to how did you generate this file or where did you get this file. It's not in the valid format as described in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#requirements-file-format. For reference, this post lists the different ways to [generate a requirements.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31684375/2745495).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your requirements.txt should be in the [format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example):

```
absl-py==1.0.0
appdirs==1.4.4
astroid==2.11.2
astunparse==1.6.3
audioread==2.1.9
black==22.3.0
cachetools==5.0.0
certifi==2021.10.8
```

Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to create/update a requirements.txt file

Comment: This is assuming the op wants to lock down their requirements to specific versions instead of minimum versions for example

Answer (score 1):

Use proper comments as descripbed in the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/):

> A line that begins with # is treated as a comment and ignored.
> Whitespace followed by a # causes the # and the remainder of the line
> to be treated as a comment.
>
> Comments are stripped after line continuations are processed.