# Is there a way to install a particular list of modules using PIP for python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I would like to install all modules in a particular file for Python 3 using a single pip command.
Is there a way to do this without having to specify every single package name?

Comment: You can explore how to use requirements.txt file to install all required packages for a project.

Comment: I just complete the answer below with `pipreqs` to generate the `requirement.txt`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/15537469

Answer (score 1):

You then install it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it installs all the packages for your project.

Answer (score 1):

make a requirement file named **requirements.txt** in your project folder and then open a terminal (powershell , command prompt or whatever you prefer) and write the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

all the packages will be installed at once

Answer (score 1):

Create a requirement.txt file and add all packages name inside that file then you can use pip install command like this:-

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

this will recursively install every package you mentioned in the requirement file.

If you want to generate requirement.txt from Django virtual environment you can use the pip freeze command:-

```
pip freeze > requirement.txt
```