# Python - View & remove all unused dependencies in requirements.txt

Tags: python, dependencies, python-packaging, requirements.txt

Somewhere along the way, the requirements.txt in my Python application has become extremely bloated. There are 100+ dependencies listed and iteratively going through it and removing each dependency until the application breaks is not an option.

Does anyone know of a tool that can show which packages in the requirements.txt are being used during runtime? If no tool exists, how has anyone solved this problem in a more efficient way than deleting packages one-by-one?

Answer (score 2):

A Python application's requirements.txt file may be analysed for unneeded dependencies using many tools.

pip-tools: Python dependency management tools. The pip-check programme can find packages in a requirements.txt file that the application is not using.

```
pip install pip-tools
pip check
```

pip-autoremove: Removes superfluous dependencies from requirements.txt files. It removes required file packages that are not imported in any source code.

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove -r requirements.txt
```

pip-updater: Automatically updates and removes dependencies. This utility can update and delete packages.

```
pip install pip-updater
pip-updater -r requirements.txt
```

pyupgrade: Automatically upgrades and removes dependencies. It may upgrade and delete packages.

```
pip install pyupgrade
pyupgrade requirements.txt
```

Pyflakes can examine imports and dependencies in contemporary Python files.

Pipdeptree can produce a dependency tree for all your dependencies and show where they are utilised in your project.

```
pip install pipdeptree
pipdeptree
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see all requirements by:

```
pip freeze # python2
pip3 freeze # python3
```

Then you should compare these with requirements.txt and remove unused dependencies.

Also you can use `pipreqs` module. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684470/15144104).